# What could be a regular expression for this sentence?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

What could be a regular expression to extract only **Hi_There_1** and **Hi_There_2** in below sentence:

```
Hi_There_1 = TRUE or Hi_There_2 = TRUE
```

I tried this:

```
/(?!TRUE)\w+/g
```

But it is matching all words.
**Note:** Words **Hi_there_1** or **Hi_there_2** can be any other strings also. The goal is to exclude ***=***, ***or*** and ***TRUE*** always.

Comment: I think I got it : "((?![or]|[TRUE]|[=])\w+)"g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if your solution works for your example, it won't give you the correct result for other input, e.g. like this `Hi_There_1 = TRUE or Torro_Rosso = TRUE`

Square brackets `[` define a *set* of characters, but not the *order* of them. So, in your solution, you excluded any word that contains the letters `T`, `R`, `U` and `E` (the same for `o` and `r`). That's why `Torro` isn't detected in the example above.

Try this regex instead: `(\w+)(?:TRUE|or|=|\s)*`

It captures the parts you want to remove in the 2nd group, but since it's a non-capture group (that's the `?:`), it doesn't return that group as a result.

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/oM4rH6/1)